# Creating MySQL table in Java with specific charset/collation. Is it possible?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a database in **latin1/latin1_general_cs** but whatever I try I always get a database created in **utf8/default collation**.

[image: MySQL Workbench Screenshot]

This is my current code:

```
MysqlDataSource mysqlDataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

mysqlDataSource.setServerName(jdbcInstance.getServer());
mysqlDataSource.setPortNumber(jdbcInstance.getPort());
mysqlDataSource.setDatabaseName(jdbcInstance.getDbName());
mysqlDataSource.setUser(jdbcInstance.getUser());
mysqlDataSource.setPassword(jdbcInstance.getPassword());

mysqlDataSource.setCreateDatabaseIfNotExist(true);
mysqlDataSource.setUseUnicode(false);
mysqlDataSource.setCharacterEncoding("latin1");
mysqlDataSource.setConnectionCollation("latin1_general_cs");

connection = mysqlDataSource.getConnection();
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just impossible to do what I want?

Comment: have you tried to call `setCreateDatabaseIfNotExist` after all the other setters?

Comment: Already tried it and the result was the same